# How to get the store id from the code

Tags: magento-1.9, stores, store-id

So I have the store code and I would really like simply the store id. Ideally I do not want to simply load the store completely as I only need the id.

One idea I had was to load this via a collection but I was wondering if there was another way via a helper or resource.

Comment: For me this works perfectly: `Mage::app()->getStore($storeCode)->getId();`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Haven't tested this but I seem to remember you can get the ID by using the method `loadConfig` in the model `Mage_Core_Model_Store`

After that you can get the ID by calling `getId()` on the model.

The `loadConfig` method uses the loaded configuration to retrieve store data

```
$store = Mage::getConfig()->getNode()->stores->{$code};
```

Which gives you the following values

- id
- code
- website_id

Comment: Strange - for me (Magento 1.9.0.0) this returns NULL. What worked for me was `Mage::getConfig()->getNode('stores')->{$code}`

Comment: Or even better : Mage::getConfig()->getNode('stores')->{$code}->{'system'}->{'store'}->{'id'};

Comment: @dougMcLean got the same problem on EE 1.14.1.0, this appears when "config" cache is enabled - looks like Magento cache issue. Sander would you be so kind to edit your answer using Mage::getConfig()->getNode('stores')->{$code}, so the solution works for both enabled/disabled cache cases?

Comment: I have multistore, how can i display selected store products using store id, my code -> justpaste.it/6fi1f

Answer (score 22):

`Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeCode, 'code')->getId()`

Isn't this the simplest way to do?

Comment: It may be simplest but might not be the best for site performance to load the full store when I only need the id.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Then direct SQL in a resource model :)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this is something that's peculiar to 1.9.0.0 but I couldn't get either `Mage::getConfig()->getNode()->stores->{$code}` or `Mage::getModel('core/store')->loadConfig($code)` (which in fact *calls* `Mage::getConfig()->getNode()->stores->{$code}`) to return anything.

The first was close... with a subtle change in form, this gets a result, though it's waaay more info than you need:

```
$store = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('stores')->{$code}
```

What worked for me, to get just the store id, was this:

```
$storeId = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('stores')->{$code}->system->store->id;
```

...still inefficient, of course, loading all that config info just for one little number. But hey, that's Magento for you.

Answer (score 4):

The following should work:

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('core/store')->loadConfig($code)->getId(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though this appears to be the same as the earlier one :)

Comment: Yes, noticed it after I posted my response :)