# Magento how do I get store_code when I have store_id

Tags: multistore, configuration

we have the opposite question from this one:
[How to get the store id from the code](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53629/how-to-get-the-store-id-from-the-code)

**question:** How do I get the Magento store_code when I have store_id? (quick without loading the whole config)

So we have ID=6 and need the code = store_EN

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this below code to get the store code using store id

```
Mage::app()->getStore($StoreId)->getCode();
```

### Note:

Magento provides *a single function*  **getStore()** by which you **`can get store data`** 
by store id or store code.

In Magento, you can load the store Object by `code /id`on **getStore()** function.

After that from  that **`StoreObject`** you can get ***store code or store id*** as per as your requirement

see at [*`Mage_Core_Model_App`*](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php#L832)  class  function at  `getStore()`.

On this function *if your parameter is numeric* then * store object is loaded by store id*

> ```
>  if (is_numeric($id)) {
>                 $store->load($id);
>             }
> ```

if param is **string** then *load store object by store code*

> ```
>  elseif (is_string($id)) {
>         $store->load($id, 'code');
>     }
> ```

---

> ```
> if (empty($this->_stores[$id])) {
>             $store = Mage::getModel('core/store');
>             /* @var $store Mage_Core_Model_Store */
>             if (is_numeric($id)) {
>                 $store->load($id);
>             } elseif (is_string($id)) {
>                 $store->load($id, 'code');
>             }
>
>             if (!$store->getCode()) {
>                 $this->throwStoreException();
>             }
>             $this->_stores[$store->getStoreId()] = $store;
>             $this->_stores[$store->getCode()] = $store;
>         }
> ```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do it quicker than loading the whole store model, you could also use a database query.

```
$resource = Mage::getModel('core/resource');
$db = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$storeCode = $db->fetchOne($db->select()->from($resource->getTableName('core_store'), 'code')->where('store_id = ?', $storeId));
```

There seems to be a group of users that seem to always advise against these type of 'direct' queries (although we're using an ORM) due to backward/forward compatibility. I usually agree, although you have to look at it on a case-by-case basis. Concerning this piece of code, there is only one table used (core_store) and that table hasn't changed since version 1.1 when multistore was introduced and won't ever change again in the 1.x range since there will only be minor updates from now on, with Magento 2 and all.