# How to get the ID of a store by name?

Tags: multistore, store-id, getmodel

Let´s say I have a store named "Megastore". How can I get the id of that specific store?

Can I do it by using some kind of filter?

```
Mage::getModel('core/store')->addFieldToFilter('name', 'Megastore');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually found the solution here: [How to get the store id from the code](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53629/how-to-get-the-store-id-from-the-code)

```
Mage::app()->getStore('Megastore')->getId()
```

Comment: Keep in mind that getStore() function will load your store by store code, not by store name.

Answer (score 1):

What do you need the ID for?  Are you writing code for a specific store?  If so you can do

```
  <?php if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() == 'default'){ ?>
```

Default being the store name.